# I have the following string "12-5" and I'm trying to parse it using TryParse in .NET. It returned true, How to acheive a false for the given string?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, datetime-format, tryparse

When giving **"12-5"** or **"12,5"** as an input to DateTime.TryParse in .NET, it is converting it to **"12-05-2020"** and the return value is **true**. How is "12-5" equal to "12-05-2020"? In my case, the input string is the user's date of birth and it is a free text as per the requirement and the parsed value "12-05-2020" makes no sense as the date of birth cant be a future date. Is there a way to correct this without using DateTime.Parse or DateTime.ParseExact as they might throw exceptions.

Comment: "makes no sense as the date of birth cant be a future date" - that's not something you can tell TryParse I don't think: you'll have to validate the date you're given after parsing it.

Comment: Maybe use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8)? And then validate the date as Rup said

Comment: Even if you're using a plaintext field for the input, you should still have a good understanding of the format you expect (and give this info to the user). Otherwise you will get e.g. a mixup of European and US date format wrt month and day: 03/04/1985 could mean both March 4th and April 3rd. And once you have an idea about the format you expect - parse it away with a proper parser.

Comment: @Rafalon, Thanks for the response. See the main problem is I can not specify any fixed format for validations. In our case, we are using scanned forms and taking the written values from those. So this restricts me from using TryParseExact

Comment: Then you just `TryParse` and hope that it will parse *correctly* any format (see Sergey's comment above about the same written date corresponding to two dates depending on the format). Then if the parse succeeds, you can validate the date as in the second point of Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have **2** tests to perform:

1. For a valid date *syntax* (say, `bla-bla-bla` is not one)
2. For a valid date *value* (say, `25-03-2123` is not one)

Let's check for these requirements in one `if`:

```
   string userInput = "12-05-15"; // 12 May 2015

   ...

   // We can use several formats in one go:
   // DateTime.TryParseExact will try formats in the given order
   string[] allowedFormats = new string[] {
     "d-M-yy", "d-M-yyyy", "MMM d yyyy",
   };

   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
          userInput.Trim(), // let's tolerate leading/trailing whitespaces
          allowedFormats,        
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
          System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
          out var result) && 
       result <= DateTime.Today &&
       result >= DateTime.Today.AddYears(-150)) {
     // result is 
     //   1. Valid date 
     //   2. At least 150 years ago
     //   3. At most today 
   }
   else {
     // userInput doesn't meet at least one criterium
   }
```

Comment: using TryParseExact, I can not restrict the string to some specific formats. In my case, the string can be of any format say, 12-05-96, 12-05-1996, Dec 05 1996 and what ever the user has given in the past. we are working with historical data and so can't expect a fixed format. Thanks

Comment: @phani bnr: in this case you can provide *several formats* within single `TryParseExact` call. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

As @Rafalon suggested, use DateTime.TryParseExact to avoid exceptions and set the format you want.

```
string dateformat = "12-05";
bool answer = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateformat, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime result);
```

Comment: Instead of `null` it's better to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as `null` means current culture which will differ on different machines and thus can lead to different parsing behaviour on different machines.

Comment: @ckuri OK. Thanks.